# How to delete from table with number stored as varchar2

Tags: oracle, sql-delete, varchar, varchar2

This might be a silly question but here we go.

Let's say I have a table 'MyTable' with one column 'Number' stored as varchar2. Is there any way to delete from  this table the lines where the value from 'Number' is smaller than my input?

Something like this:

```
delete from MyTable where Number<'MyValueAsVarchar2'
```

For example, I have a record '5'.

```
delete from MyTable where Number<'7'
```

This statement deletes  the row.

However if I replace '7' with '10', it doesn't work anymore. (my guess is because '1' is smaller than '5')

I'm using Oracle.

Comment: `delete from MyTable where cast(Number as int)  < 7`

Comment: @juergend Thanks a lot, it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TO_NUMBER function to convert varchar2 to number:

delete from MyTable where TO_NUMBER(Number)<7